# Bad Mask /29 for address 172.24.59.0 255.255.255.248 cisco packet tracer

Tags: linux, unix

I received this error Bad Mask /29 for address 172.24.59.0  255.255.255.248  Why was this error produced?

and what is the valid host range for the 255.255.255.248 subnet?

would the correct answer for the first part be because the correct IP address should be 172.24.59.1 255.255.255.248  ???

and part 2
172.24.59.1 - 172.24.59.6

Answer (score 1):

The `172.24.59.0/29` would be

```
from  10101100.00011000.00111011.00000000  172.24.59.0
  to  10101100.00011000.00111011.00000111  172.24.59.7
mask  11111111.11111111.11111111.11111000  255.255.255.248
```

Because the host identifier `000` is reserved for network itself and the `111` for the *broadcast address*, you can't use them in a network address, but in the error message it's expressed from another perspective: the mask is invalid for the given IP address.

Then, what would be a suitable mask?

- A mask `<24`, e.g. `172.24.59.0/23`

  ```
   from  10101100.00011000.00111010.00000000  172.24.58.0
     to  10101100.00011000.00111011.11111111  172.24.59.255
   mask  11111111.11111111.11111110.00000000  255.255.254.0
  ```
- Because the `172.24.59.0` must be within `172.16.0.0/12` [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) *private network*, the other end is not limited technically, but by an IANA allocation.

  ```
   from  10101100.00010000.00000000.00000000  172.16.0.0
     to  10101100.00011111.11111111.11111111  172.31.255.255
   mask  11111111.11110000.00000000.00000000  255.240.0.0
  ```

That's the theory behind this.

In your use case, you'd probably use e.g. `172.24.58.1/29` instead of `172.24.58.0/29`.